# Really easy Rails Active-Record Associations question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 2 models:

```
class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :missions
end
```

And I have a complex Mission find statement:

```
@missions = Mission.send(@view, level).send(@show).search(@search).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => actual_sort, :per_page => 50
```

I'd like to add to my query the possibility to search for a specific category too.
I tried this but it does not work:

```
@missions = Mission.send(@view, level).send(@show).send(:category, @category).search(@search).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => actual_sort, :per_page => 50
```

Rails says that Mission has not a .category method.  How would you solve this?

Thanks,
Augusto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH ... MY ... GOD

Are you sure this is the best way to be doing this?

I don't think people will be able to help you if you don't explain a bit more, but I highly doubt that you couldn't write your statement like so:

```
@missions = Mission.select("missions.level ...,category.attr ...").where(["missions.level = ? ...", level ...]).includes(:category).where(["categories.field = ?", ...]).paginate(...)
```

Obviously the elipses (...) mean generally etc.

This is a working example on one of my projects in testing:

```
i = Item.where("items.name like '%Coupon%'").includes(:category).where(["categories.name = ? ",'Category 2'])
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your hint helped me find the solution:

Comment: named_scope :category, lambda {|category| {:conditions => ["categories.name =?",  category]} if category != ""}

Answer (score 0):

try performing the where selection on category_id